# UIImagePngRepresentation sometimes cause memory leak

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, uiimagepngrepresentation, vmalloc

My code shows weird behavior, and I've searched for hours with no luck.

My code snippet:

```
func loadImageFromLocal(index:String)->UIImage{
        var fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        var containerURL = fileManager.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier("group.mygroup.test")
        var pngNumber=sharedDefaults.objectForKey("png\(index)") as Int
        var filePath = containerURL!.path!+"/img\(pngNumber).png"

        NSLog(filePath)

        var image:UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)!
        return image
}

...

var image:UIImage?=loadImageFromLocal(button.titleForState(.Normal)!)
var pngImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

As you can see, I save image to local folder and when I need it, I load it from  load image from local folder and convert it as NSData with UIImagePNGRepresentation

Weird thing is, for some image, it works as I expected. However, for some image, the memory won't deallocated. (Checked with Allocation instrument. The heap keeps going up)

[image: second one is deallocated, first one is alive (see the dot representing it is alive)]

See the dot meaning the first one is still alive?
I checked the history, and when it goes well, it should be like this[image]

For the problematic image, it is like this
[image]

Two alloc, one dealloc..I guess that is the problem but I don't know why it happens only for specific image.
When I check the stack trace, I guess it means UIImagePNGRepresentation is the problem but I have no idea what this means exactly so I will attach the stack trace.
[image]

Any help will be appreciated!! Thanks!!

Comment: Did you find a solution?